# How to make 2 password fields match with PHP form validation?

Tags: php, validation

Could someone please help me. I am a beginner and I am trying to make two password fields match with PHP functions. Help? Code below...

```
function validateMemberPasswordRepeat($memberPasswordRepeat){
                if(preg_match("$memberPasswordRepeat === $memberPassword", $memberPasswordRepeat)){
                      return true;
                   }else{
                       return false;
                 }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide both passwords to the function and no need of preg_match a regular comparison will work

```
function validateMemberPasswordRepeat($memberPasswordRepeat,$memberPassword) { 
    if($memberPasswordRepeat === $memberPassword) 
        {         
          return true; 
        } 
        else 
        {
          return false; 
        } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use Javascript onclick event

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function validatePasswords()
   {
      var pass1=document.getElementById('pass1').value;
      var pass2=document.getElementById('pass2').value;
      if(! pass1==pass2) 
       {
          alert("passwords don't match");
          return false;
       }
      return true;
   }
</script>
<form action=".." method="..">
   <input type="password" name="pass1"/><br/>
   <input type="password" name="pass2"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" onclick="return validatePasswords();"/>
</form>
```

Comment: "Use Javascript" is not a valid answer to "How do I do xyz with PHP?"

Comment: i know it's not a valid PHP answer , but if the main point is to validate the two fields , Javascript usage here is simple

Comment: You cannot rely on Javascript validation. While it is a nice feature, people can still disable Javascript or alter the code and you would end up with no validation at all, leaving your site open to attacks of all sorts. Whether or not you have client-side validation, you should always validate data on the server.